# jq: error: Cannot index array with string

Tags: json, jq

I`m trying to do a bash script for a checkpoint management server api and I am experiencing some problems. 
I want to get the value in a json dictionary and for that I have to use variables. I am entering this command:

```
echo $rulebase | jq --arg n "$0" '.rulebase[$n].to'
```

and I get the next error:

> jq: error: Cannot index array with string

However, If i use :

```
echo $rulebase | jq  '.rulebase[0].to'
```

I get the result that I need. I dont know how to use the variables when they are a number, can anyone help me?

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.  What is `$rulebase` ? What is the value of `$0` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert the string that you give to your script to a *number*.

```
echo "$rulebase" | jq --arg n "$1" '.rulebase[$n|tonumber].to'
```

Comment: JQ docs for the 'tonumber' function: https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#tonumber

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pass in a numeric value, use

```
—-argjson
```

instead of `—-arg`, which is for JSON string values.

If your jq does not support —argjson, then now would be an excellent time to upgrade if possible; otherwise, you could use `tonumber`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the index number in `$0`, just let the shell insert it by using appropriate quotes:

```
echo $rulebase | jq ".rulebase[$0].to"
```

(this being strange, having a number in `$0`, which normally is the program name).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass numbers as JSON args. Here

```
echo "$rulebase" | jq --argjson n "$my_variable" '.rulebase[$n].to'
```