# jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string

Tags: jq, amazon-ecs

I have a for loop in a bash script where I want to change the image name in a JSON file.

However, it gives me an error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "0"
```

Here is the for loop:

```bash
NEW_IMAGE='xxxxxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/virtual-layer-robot:xxxxxx'
for (( i=1 ; i<=10 ; i++ ));
do
    NEW_IMAGE=$NEW_IMAGE$i
    j=$((i-1))
    NEW_TASK_DEFINITION=$(echo $TASK_DEFINITION | jq -r --arg IMAGE "$NEW_IMAGE" --arg j "$j" '.taskDefinition | .containerDefinitions[$j].image = $IMAGE | del(.taskDefinitionArn) | del(.revision) | del(.status) | del(.requiresAttributes) | del(.compatibilities) | del(.registeredAt) | del (.registeredBy)')
done
```

This is my JSON (TASK_DEFINITION):

```json
{
    "taskDefinition": {
        "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:xxxxxx:task-definition/virtual-xxxx-robot-task-xxxxxx:38",
        "containerDefinitions": [
            {
                "name": "virtual-robot-1",
                "image": "xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/virtual-layer-robot:xxxxxx",
                "cpu": 0,
                "portMappings": [
                    {
                        "containerPort": 89,
                        "hostPort": 89,
                        "protocol": "tcp"
                    }
                ],
                "essential": false,
                "environment": [
                    {
                        "name": "CROSS_ACCOUNT_ROLE",
                        "value": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/xxxxxx-xxx-xxxxxx-xxxx"
                    }
                ],
                "mountPoints": [],
                "volumesFrom": [],
                "logConfiguration": {
                    "logDriver": "awslogs",
                    "options": {
                        "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                        "awslogs-group": "/ecs/virtual-layer-robot-2010",
                        "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                    }
                }
            },
{
                "name": "virtual-robot-2",
                "image": "xxxxxxx.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/virtual-layer-robot:xxxxxx",
                "cpu": 0,
                "portMappings": [
                    {
                        "containerPort": 89,
                        "hostPort": 89,
                        "protocol": "tcp"
                    }
                ],
                "essential": false,
                "environment": [
                    {
                        "name": "CROSS_ACCOUNT_ROLE",
                        "value": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx"
                    }
                ],
                "mountPoints": [],
                "volumesFrom": [],
                "logConfiguration": {
                    "logDriver": "awslogs",
                    "options": {
                        "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                        "awslogs-group": "/ecs/virtual-layer-robot-2010",
                        "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "family": "virtual-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-definition",
        "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/xxxxxxx",
        "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/xxxxxxx",
        "networkMode": "awsvpc",
        "revision": 38,
        "volumes": [],
        "status": "ACTIVE",
        "requiresAttributes": [
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
            },
            {
                "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
            },
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
            },
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
            },
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
            },
            {
                "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
            },
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
            },
            {
                "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
            },
            {
                "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
            }
        ],
        "placementConstraints": [],
        "compatibilities": [
            "EC2",
            "FARGATE"
        ],
        "runtimePlatform": {
            "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
            "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
        },
        "requiresCompatibilities": [
            "FARGATE"
        ],
        "cpu": "1024",
        "memory": "3072",
        "registeredAt": "2023-04-26T17:25:22.400000+05:30",
        "registeredBy": "arn:aws:sts::xxxxx:assumed-role/xxx-xxxxx-xxxx/xxxxx.xxxx"
    },
    "tags": []
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quote your variable: `echo "$TASK_DEFINITION"`

Comment: Array indices are numbers. Use `--argjson` instead of `--arg`.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:jquery]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jq: error: Cannot index array with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261746/jq-error-cannot-index-array-with-string)